# No tinyusb CDC's callback is called

Tags: c++, mcu, rp2040

I'm making my own simple number pad. it's gift for my older sister. but, I faced critical problem on `USB-CDC` communication part. I wrote USB descriptor that has two configurations. one is `HID(Human Interface Device)` and other one is `CDC (Communication Device Class)`. and `CDC` will be for configuring the hardware and getting `User Defined Function` works that an external software is installed on the user computer.

I'm using `tinyusb` library to initialize `RP2040`'s USB device interface. and I implemented that `HID` and `CDC TX` works. but `CDC RX` is never working.

Full schematic and its firmware source code can be found in [my repository](https://github.com/jay94ks/simple-np).

#### Video in GIF.

[image]

I'm trying to debug my hardware, like this:

```
extern "C" void tud_cdc_rx_cb(uint8_t itf) {
    char temp[3] = {0, };
    tft_print("DATA RECV: ");  // --> never,... never... NEVER.... :!!!!!!!!
    temp[0] = 'a' + itf;
    temp[1] =  '\n';
    tft_print(temp);

    uint8_t buf[64] = {0, };
    uint32_t len = tud_cdc_n_read(itf, buf, sizeof(buf));

    if (len) {
        msg_frame_receive(buf, len);
    }
}
```

but, it never be called. :(
how can i make this work?

Comment: Why do you expect this callback to be called?  Are you running some software on the PC side that connects to the RP2040's virtual serial port and sends data to it?  We can't troubleshoot that piece if you don't give any details about it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson today, I solved this problem, and its works perfectly now. but, as answer for you, this callback is promised to be called by `tinyUSB` when VCP data received. but it doesn't be called even the PC software sends many bytes.

Comment: @DavidGrayson The first paragraph of this problem explains the functions of the HW, and the second paragraph explains the libraries used and what does not work. The callback function written in the last paragraph is a predefined callback function in the `tinyusb` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved today.
It was solved by updating `pico-sdk`'s `tinyusb` library to recent branch. and the callback is called perfectly. And the callback is promised to be called when the `VCP` data received at `RP2040`. of course, the sender of data is `PC`.

I don't know actual reason why this problem could be solved by updating `tinyusb` library. but i just updated it and, it solved.

**See issue page on github for details**:
https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb/issues/2537

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).